# JavaScript loop to create innerHTML (Google Sheet)

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am grabbing some data using a Google Sheet as my source.  I have three similar queries happening but only two are return results and working within my table cells.  After looking around I see people looping to create the id=# to include in their HTML but I can't quite figure out the syntax to do this with mine.

Here is what I am currently using, (WARNING: Noobie Code Ahead)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['gauge']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(queryValue);
function queryValue () {
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=B22:B37&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=7');
query.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data = response.getDataTable();

    // fetch the data from range B22:B37 into the span "bx"
    // These are date labels 
    document.getElementById('b22').innerHTML = data.getValue(0, 0);
    document.getElementById('b23').innerHTML = data.getValue(1, 0);
    document.getElementById('b24').innerHTML = data.getValue(2, 0);
    document.getElementById('b25').innerHTML = data.getValue(3, 0);
    document.getElementById('b26').innerHTML = data.getValue(4, 0);
    document.getElementById('b27').innerHTML = data.getValue(5, 0);
    document.getElementById('b28').innerHTML = data.getValue(6, 0);
    document.getElementById('b29').innerHTML = data.getValue(7, 0);
    document.getElementById('b30').innerHTML = data.getValue(8, 0);
    document.getElementById('b31').innerHTML = data.getValue(9, 0);
    document.getElementById('b32').innerHTML = data.getValue(10, 0);
    document.getElementById('b33').innerHTML = data.getValue(11, 0);
    document.getElementById('b34').innerHTML = data.getValue(12, 0);
    document.getElementById('b35').innerHTML = data.getValue(13, 0);
    document.getElementById('b36').innerHTML = data.getValue(14, 0);
    document.getElementById('b37').innerHTML = data.getValue(15, 0);
});
}
google.setOnLoadCallback(queryValue1);
function queryValue1 () {
var query = new google.visualization.Query('https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/tq?range=A22:A37&key=0AhCv9Xu_eRnSdFNhSzNQUFd3b1ZfRHgtQURINFpzeGc&gid=7');
query.send(function (response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
        alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
        return;
    }
    var data1 = response.getDataTable();

    // fetch the data from range A22:A37 into the span "bx"
    // These are the labels on the top of the gauges and I want to turn the color of the gauge range. (i.e. <70:red, 71-89:yellow, 90-100:red)
    document.getElementById('a22').innerHTML = data1.getValue(0, 0);
    document.getElementById('a23').innerHTML = data1.getValue(1, 0);
    document.getElementById('a24').innerHTML = data1.getValue(2, 0);
    document.getElementById('a25').innerHTML = data1.getValue(3, 0);
    document.getElementById('a26').innerHTML = data1.getValue(4, 0);
    document.getElementById('a27').innerHTML = data1.getValue(5, 0);
    document.getElementById('a28').innerHTML = data1.getValue(6, 0);
    document.getElementById('a29').innerHTML = data1.getValue(7, 0);
    document.getElementById('a30').innerHTML = data1.getValue(8, 0);
    document.getElementById('a31').innerHTML = data1.getValue(9, 0);
    document.getElementById('a32').innerHTML = data1.getValue(10, 0);
    document.getElementById('a33').innerHTML = data1.getValue(11, 0);
    document.getElementById('a34').innerHTML = data1.getValue(12, 0);
    document.getElementById('a35').innerHTML = data1.getValue(13, 0);
    document.getElementById('a36').innerHTML = data1.getValue(14, 0);
    document.getElementById('a37').innerHTML = data1.getValue(15, 0);
});
}
```

Comment: do u know the concept of for-loop ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do a loop, you can use a starting point, and an ending point, then simply use each incremented value in your code.

---

Since you're basically looping from `0` to `15`, the start will be `0`, and the inclusive end will be `15`. Your `ID` is simply offset by `22` and preceded by `"b"`, so we use addition to offset the number, and concatenation to join the `"b"`.

```
for (var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
    document.getElementById('b' + (i + 22)).innerHTML = data.getValue(i, 0);
}
```